# How to poll async method to Update ObservableCollections in a ViewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, polling

I have been following this [blog by Stephen Cleary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn605875.aspx) I have read a lot of his work and allot of other resources online.

What I posted works(for Initialisation) but I would like to know the best solution for polling the JSON from an API without locking up the UI.

I came across information that says's

> Windows platforms are serious about UI components being accessed only from the UI thread that owns them.

My app has two list boxes both populated with observable collections. Listbox one contained the Players and list box two contains the list of player stats. I would like to update both listboxes whilst listbox one keeps its selected items.

What I would like to know is what would be the safest way to update the ViewModel every 10 seconds from the json without locking up the UI.

Do I run my poll on a separate thread or use the DispatcherTimer(If the server takes more than the ten second to respond which timer handles this situation best)?

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<PlayerJSON>> FetchPlayerData()
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "player", Password = "pass1" } })
    using (var wc = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var data = await wc.GetStringAsync(new Uri(@"https://players.json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var DeserializeTask = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<PlayerJSON>>(data)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return DeserializeTask;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<NotifyTaskCompletion<PlayerJSON>> _PlayerJSON;
public ObservableCollection<NotifyTaskCompletion<PlayerJSON> PlayerJSON
{
    get => _PlayerJSON;
    set
    {
        if (_PlayerJSON != value)
        {
            _PlayerJSON = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

async Task GetPlayerJSON()
{
    PlayerJSON = new NotifyTaskCompletion<PlayerJSON>(FetchPlayerData());
}
```

Update:

```
async Task GetPlayerJSON()
{
    while (updating)
    {
        // This has a gitter in the view every 20 seconds
        PlayerJSON = new NotifyTaskCompletion<PlayerJSON>(FetchPlayerData());

        await Task.Delay(20000); // arbitrary delay
    }
}

// Invoke when the view is loaded
async public Task Initialise()
{
    await GetPlayerJSON();
}
```

Comment: `DispatchTimer` is a good choice.  If you want to avoid the problem of the timer "over-running" its self if the task takes too long. just make it a non-repeating timer that you restart once the previous task completes.  You can use a `StopWatch` to measure how long the task took, and subtract that amount from your interval when restarting the timer.

Comment: If you're interested in async, you could consider using await Task.Delay() rather than a dispatcher timer. To retain selected items, you could compare the new list to the original, adding and removing. Or maybe your list is just of changes.  Maybe consider every 20 seconds rather than 10. That rather depends on how many players you will have polling though.

Comment: I have updated my question with `Task.Delay()` Is good practice to set a completely new object each time or is it better to compare/and update existing object.

Comment: Am I wrong to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on GetStringAsync? because I will need the string to Deserialise the JSON.